# How to centralize boilerplate constructor code in C#?

Tags: c#

All of my models in all of my applications inherit from `IEntity`:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    dynamic RelatedItems { get; set; }
}
```

To prevent `NullReferenceException`, I always write a constructor in each model:

```
public class Book : IEntity
{
   public Book()
   {
       RelatedItems = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
   }

   // other properties of the book
}
```

I need the `RelatedItems` because my infrastructure does many things on it.

However, this boilerplate constructor is a true pain.

When C# introduced [Default Implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/) I thought maybe default constructors also exist now, thus I created a constructor in my `IEntity` interface.

But I got this error:

> IEntity.cs(7,16): error CS0526: Interfaces cannot contain instance constructors

Is there a way that I can prevent this boilerplate code?

I once tried to change it to **abstract** base class but it messed with EF Core and its inheritance.

Comment: Is using a (abstract) factory pattern suitable? Or changing the design to use composition or aggregation controlled by the property? Also using generics instead of dynamic?

Comment: As long as your public setter is there, those nullrefs won't go away, but I am missing a bit of the context why you would feel setting up your class properly is a nuisance :)

Comment: `public abstract class BoilerPlateBase : IEntity...  public class Book : BoilerPlateBase...`?

Comment: IMHO the class should control the constructor, allowing a 'default constructor' using an interface looks problematic

Comment: What does `dynamic` do for you that `object` wouldn't?

Comment: @Icepickle, because it's the same code repeated without any change. Isn't that the definition of boilerplate code?

Comment: @AlanK, EF Core throws a lot of problems when it comes to inheritance. But with interfaces it shows no problems.

Comment: @AlanK, EF Core throws a lot of problems when it comes to inheritance. But with interfaces it shows no problems.

Comment: @Enigmativity, dynamic assignment. For exapmle `book.RelatedItems.CalculatedPrice = 50;`. This line of code can't be done using `object`.

Comment: @HosseinFallah - That's a dangerous piece of code. `dynamic` is best used when you are using dynamic data. In production code, when working with standard C# objects, it's best to use reflection and call strongly-typed code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code.
It's better to use generic instead of dynamic, so I added a *BookRelatedItem* class which you can add any further properties to.
About the *EntityBase* class, it's an abstraction of your entities so you don't have to initialize your RelatedItems each time.

```
    public interface IEntity<T> where T : class
    {
        long Id { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<T> RelatedItems { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class EntityBase<T> : IEntity<T> where T : class
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> RelatedItems { get; set; }

        public EntityBase()
        {
            RelatedItems = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    public class Book : EntityBase<BookRelatedItem>
    {
        // other properties of the book
    }

    public class BookRelatedItem
    {
        //some props
    }
```

Comment: I agree that this code seems related to the OP's code, but it breaks so many things in the original design and it seems to commit the same sin that OP is trying to avoid with the abstract class. Can you explain how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

As @AlanK pointed out the easiest thing would be to create an abstract class providing a boilerplate implementation of your properties including any initializers like this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntitiy : IEntity
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual dynamic RelatedItems { get; set; } = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
}
```

you can then inherit your `Book` class from `BaseEntity` overriding properties as needed:

```cs
public class Book : BaseEntitiy
{
    // example override if you need any special getters or setters for books
    public override long Id
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                base.Id = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This poses problems in EF Core as I mentioned in the question. EF Core has no problems with interfaces, but has a lot of problems with base classes and inheirtance.

Comment: @HosseinFallah Interesting, at work we also use EF Core and an inheritance depth of up to 5 classes and it works fine. May I ask if you use Code First or Database First with EF Core? Also which problems do the base classes cause in your case?